# Why can my Express server not receive the POST request?

Tags: express, axios

I use **Axios** to send `FormData` to my **Express** back-end, which works fine when I do not include the `config` object as a third argument. However, when the `config` object is included, a CORS error appears: [screenshot of CORS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBRrD.png)

The problem should not be with the front-end code, as there is no issue when I send the same request (`config` included) to https://httpbin.org/post. I even receive the progress of the file upload from there - which is ultimately what I am after in my own back-end code. I know that this is achieved by parsing the `FormData`, but I have not bothered working on that part yet, as I still have issues with the actual request coming through.

Note that I am able to successfully receive the request on the back-end if I exclude the `config` object, like so:

```
await axios.post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API}/upload`, formData);
```

This is what my request should look like, and what is currently working through the external endpoint, as mentioned before. However, the same request also results in a CORS error when sent to my own POST endpoint:

```
const config = {
  signal: controller.signal,
  onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
    progress.value = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);
  }
};

await axios.post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API}/upload`, formData, config);
```

This is what my POST endpoint currently looks like:

```
router.post('/', (request, response) => {
  response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  console.log(request);
});
```

How should I modify my POST endpoint, so that it can receive the `config` object as well? I assume that **Axios** transmits that information as headers, but it would seem that my endpoint is not equipped to handle the request anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to allow headers on the back-end.

```
response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
```